# How does Drupal.org's packaging script works?

Tags: community-official-site

Is Drupal.org's packaging script publicly accessible? How does it works? What tools does it use to fetch a module and package it as a tarball? What are the best practices in building a nightly builds for Drupal modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projects on drupal.org are managed by the [Project](http://drupal.org/project/project) project, which also contains the scripts for this. Some drupal.org specific code (for example the zip. and tar.gz packaging implementations) are also in the [Drupal.org customizations](http://drupal.org/project/drupalorg) project.